# Download Print Preview File

Tags: jquery

Working on web project using JSF 2.2, Bootstrap and jQuery.
We have functionality for Print and Download (as links) offered on the screen.

For Print, using below code and it works fine. How to download the same content as we printed in PDF file?

Thanks for  your help.

```
function printFunction() {
    $("#overview_tab").addClass("in");
    $("#myToggleDiv").addClass('in');
    $("#RUIFW-main-content").removeClass("noprint");
     $("body").removeClass("modalPrint");
     $("#printPageCreated").removeClass("noprint");
    $("#headerData").addClass("noprint");
    $("#printFooterExtraText").addClass("noprint");

    window.print();

}
```

Comment: How is this jsf related?

Comment: it's not, removed jsf tag. any ideas? trying https://parall.ax/products/jspdf, but it prints the text and not HTML